# Cannot install .NET Core 3.1 using Fedora 31

Tags: .net-core

I followed the documentation for installing .NET Core 3.1 using Fedora 31 with the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-fedora30

The commands I ran was:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo wget -q -O /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/fedora/30/prod.repo
```

Followed by:

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

It keeps reporting the package as not found. See terminal output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:14:48 ago on Thu 05 Dec 2019 15:44:56 GMT.
No match for argument: dotnet-sdk-3.1
Error: Unable to find a match: dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Are the docs wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `dnf`, but I know with `apt` that you have to do `apt-get update` to retrieve a list of packages, is there something equivalent for `dnf`?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this with aptitude on Ubuntu. Dnf however only offers `dnf clean expire-cache` which does not fix the problem.

Comment: Okay, try `sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1.100` instead

Comment: Did one better, `dnf search dotnet-sdk-3.1` it came back with `dotnet-sdk-3.1.x86_64 : Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.100 3.1.100`. Looks like the docs are wrong.

Comment: `sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1.x86_64` did not work

Comment: ```sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1.100``` did not work

Answer (score 3):

Since Fedora 32 the dotnet SDK repository comes build-in :

- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DotNet
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-fedora32

What worked for me was :

1. Remove old repository from package manager

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
```

2. Clean dnf cache

```
sudo dnf clean all
```

3. Remove all dotnet packages

```
sudo dnf remove dotnet*
```

Hint: If you're using fish or zsh as your regular shell run the command in bash

4. And reinstall the SDK :

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Comment: Faced the same issue after upgrading from Fedora 31. Your solution worked for me. Maybe add `sudo dnf remove dotnet*` as optional step.

Answer (score 1):

have you typed **sudo dnf update** before?
I just installed in Fedora 31 and gone well.

Comment: Yup, tried that it came back with ```Last metadata expiration check: 2:00:23 ago on Thu 05 Dec 2019 15:44:56 GMT.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!```

Comment: Trying this right now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?tabs=linux.

Comment: Even after trying to navigate to https://packages.microsoft.com/fedora/30/prod/ and download and install the package directly, anaconda reports `Unable to install dotnet-sdk-3.1: Could not depsolve transaction; 1 problem detected`. Trying work work how which log is reporting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This tends to happen on a system that has been upgraded from fedora 30 to 31 and has had a version of dotnet core previously installed.

I went nuclear and deleted all my dotnet shared folders(warning! you will lose all dotnet references):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/dotnet
sudo rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
sudo wget -q -O /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/fedora/30/prod.repo
```

I then found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505625/fedora-29-repo-issue.

Then ran the following:

```
sudo dnf clean all
sudo dnf upgrade
```

After this I tried the install again and it worked:

```
sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo wget -q -O /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo https://packages.microsoft.com/config/fedora/30/prod.repo
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

I am not clear on why this worked. Will teach me for treating my fedora system as a pet! :)

Comment: Maybe the `magic sauce` here was `sudo dnf clean all`. Not sure, I have seen mirrors deliver duff packages all the time while doing packer builds in AWS for ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, helped me too. I agree with opinion that `sudo dnf clean all` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading my system from Fedora 31 to Fedora 32 my dotnet command was broken with the error message.

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
```

The dotnet core package was installed before the upgrade itself with the method descibed in the question.

After inspecting what dotnet packages I had on my system with

```
sudo dnf list installed 'dotnet*'
```

the list showed SDKs 2.1, 2.2 and 3.1 as well.

To solve this, I tried to remove the dotnet-sdk-3.1 via

```
sudo dnf remove dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

and cleaned dnf caches with

```
sudo dnf clean all
```

but after a re-installation the problem persisted.

My solution was to remove **all** dotnet packages that were listed with the dnf command from above.

After that, I ran

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

And the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing `dotnet-sdk-3.1` on Fedora 32 without having dotnet installed before. But, I was not able to make it work with dnf, I always got:

`It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs`.

The solution for me was to download the Linux x64 Binaries from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core, unzip the tar.gz to a directory, and add the directory to the path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused by the location where the SDK is installed. When you run the command:
`dnf rq -l dotnet-sdk-3.1`
It states that the sdk is installed under /usr/share/dotnet/ and not under /usr/lib64/dotnet/ the location where the actual executable is installed.

When you inspect the location you find that more is installed there, like they want to move the location of the software but did half a job. So what I did ...  moved everything to /usr/lib64/dotnet/ and then replaced the folder /usr/share/dotnet with a link to /usr/lib64/dotnet.